# Xcode visible part of PNG-Image (SpriteNode) as touchable area

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, image, sprite-kit

I am currently working on a new project and I need to detect whether my SpriteNode has been touched or not. That is not the problem [yet]. But my SpriteNode includes an Png-Image and due to this it also includes an translucent part. And what I want to do is to "delete"/ignore this non-visible part and only detect whether the visible part has been touched. I tried it on several ways but nothing really worked. I need an reliable way to do that (Swift 4 or 3). I already read other posts but they did not help. 
Or maybe you have other ways to determine an touchable area from Png-Image than using a SpriteNode.

Comment: Show what you did, pixel perfect detection is always going to be a problem with no clear cut best answer